# JS events don't work properly on woocommerce cart page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, woocommerce

I am using this script for converting numbers to other formats:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
      jQuery( 'body' )
      .on( 'update_checkout updated_checkout updated_cart_totals', function() {
      var els = document.querySelectorAll('.woocommerce-Price-amount, .amount, .product-quantity');
      els.forEach(function(item) {
      item.textContent = persianJs(item.textContent).englishNumber().toString();
      });
   });
});
```

It works on *Checkout page* but it does not work on *Cart page* properly; After changing quantity of product and click on Update cart button, I see ***"Quantity" phrase*** instead of ***quantity value (number)*** in front of product name.

This is related code in cart.php:

```
$product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                                array(
                                    'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'    => '0',
                                    'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                                ),
                                $_product,
                                false
               );
```

Is there any conflict for reading `Quantity value` with `item.textContent`?

Answer (score 0):

I had used `.product-quantity` for using in Checkout page but now changed it to `strong.product-quantity` and now the script works in both Cart and Checkout page.